# Remove characters of string-like index after specified character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Is there a way to remove the characters after a specified character in an index for a Pandas DataFrame?

I have been using the censusdata package for some data analysis and it outputs the data to a DataFrame with the index as the censusgeo info (e.g.  Anaheim city, California: Summary level: 160, state:06 place:02000) I want to change the index to only be 'Anaheim city, California'. What is the best way to do this? Is it possible in python? 
Could it be easier to do in html? I am already using DataFrame.to_html()  as my output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example:

```
"Anaheim city, California: Summary level: 160, state:06 place:02000".split(":",maxsplit=1)[0]                        
Out: 'Anaheim city, California'
```

Replace the old index with a new one:

```
newindex= [ idx.split(":",maxsplit=1)[0] for idx in df.index ]
df.index=newindex
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with this result:   newindex = [idx.split(":",maxsplit=1)[0] for idx in df.index]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
AttributeError: 'censusgeo' object has no attribute 'split'.

Comment: I figured out how to get what I want as the censusgeo object has the name Arg which is just what I want. df.index.name returns 'Anaheim city,  California' thank you